# array of appointments being chosen instead of one appointment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, update-attributes

Okay so I am trying to allow a student to choose an appointment with a professor from a table of available appointments. when I press "choose" it takes all the appointment_id's from the table and then puts the first number in the table that shows chosen appointments. so instead of choosing appointment id 5 it chooses 2, 4, 5, 6. Then it puts 2 in the chosen appointments table. What I want it to do is choose the appointment that I actually selected.

HERE IS MY appointments_available VIEW(I'm only including the necessary code):

```
<% @appointment.each do |appointment|%>
<tr>
  <td><%= appointment.professor_id %></td>
  <td><%= appointment.student_id %></td>
  <td><%= appointment.timeslot %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Choose', :controller => "appointments", :action => "student_edit", :id => @appointment %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

HERE IS THE appointments CONTROLLER(again, not all the code is there):

```
def appointments_available
  @appointment = Appointment.find_all_by_student_id("")
end

def student_edit
  @appointment = Appointment.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @appointment.update_attribute(:student_id, session[:student].user_id)
end
```

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: It's usually a lot cleaner to use a proper resourceful route declared in `config/routes.rb` and use REST-ful naming conventions to conform with the defaults. For instance, this could be `appointment_path(@appointment)` instead of the Rails 1 style controller and action declaration. Also using a GET method to update a record is probably a very bad idea since some browsers will pre-fetch links like that and screw everything up badly. Use `:method => :post` where you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your actual issue is in your loop:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Choose', :controller => "appointments", :action => "student_edit", :id => @appointment %></td>
```

should be:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Choose', :controller => "appointments", :action => "student_edit", :id => appointment.id %></td>
```

Most importantly, you should try to be more RESTful and stick with the standard actions in your rails controllers, your senario does not represent the need to **not** follow best practices.

```
<% @appointments.each do |appointment|%>
<tr>
  <td><%= appointment.professor_id %></td>
  <td><%= appointment.student_id %></td>
  <td><%= appointment.timeslot %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Choose', edit_appointment_path(appointment) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

If you are listing a collection I'd name your instance variable plurally. Any use of `find_all_by_` will return an array and in your case, probably a collection from `Arel`. Also this appears to be your index action, so I'd try to use it as such.

```
def index
  @appointments = Appointment.all
end
```

You used the method name `appointments_available`, if you have a scope of `available` I'd move that into your model so you then you could call `Appointment.available`.

In your edit action you didn't need to use `_by_id` find already will find by.

```
@appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
```

But before you just start implementing my changes be sure to understand how REST works, and maybe generate a scaffold to see how a generic model would be setup, in all honesty when thinking about resources **most of the time** your situation will use the regular RESTful actions.

It's not like against the rules to name your actions something different, but you lose a lot of the conventions granted to you by Rails' opinionated design.

After you make your scaffold, take a peek at your routes by running `rake routes`, you'll see what options you have for routes. For example if you have an `edit` action in your controller, you'll also have an `edit_appointment` route which you can use by passing the appointment you want to edit to it like so: `edit_appointment_path(@appointment)`.